# PHP Session Variables won't persist in IE 11 / Windows 7 only

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

Not sure if anyone else has experienced something similar.  This seems to only affect Windows 7 / IE 11.

The symptom is that my PHP session variables won't persist when my code runs specifically on Windows 7 / IE 11.  Here are the relevant snippets:

Initial Page (where session vars are set):

```
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
session_start();
$_SESSION["UserId"] = "Test";
header('Location: '. "page2.php");
session_write_close();
exit();
```

Page2.php:

```
session_start();
echo("UserId:".$_SESSION["UserId"]);
```

In the above case, $_SESSION["UserId"] is null.

Again, the code works on all other platforms, so I suspect it's something specific to IE 11 that runs on Windows 7.  Anyone else experienced this?  Any workarounds?

Thank you!

Comment: Where the heck does `$contents["UserId"]` come from? Try making it a string like so `$_SESSION["UserId"] = 'someAmazingUserId';`

Comment: Are your Internet Explorer security settings set to some obscenely strict setting? Try lowering the security settings.

Comment: There is nothing in Win 7 / IE 11 that should prevent this from working. Sessions are not client-specific, they're server-specific. Check the logs, perhaps?

Comment: Apparently, session cookies may be disabled by default with IE11 (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/ie11-enable-session-cookies-is-disabled-by-default/230ee697-7371-421b-8e8f-ee2aee7456aa) and there are also known bugs with persistence (https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810700/subject-ie11-is-losing-cookie-information-and-thus-becoming-detached-from-a-web-application-session)